# Xcode 7 iOS app not working on device

Tags: ios, swift

Downloaded the Xcode 7 beta which allows users to test their apps on their own iOS devices. My app is supposed to stream music from a server.

On the simulator, my app works fine - it plays in the app, as well as when I quit the app.

On my device, the app does NOT play music when it enters the background. I already did the thing with changing the capabilities of the target and checking the "audio and airplay" boxes in Background Modes.

Code for the stream:

```
    stream = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: NSURL(string: "http://45.33.72.76:8000/stream/6/")!)

    stream.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    stream.view.sizeToFit()

    stream.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming

    self.view.addSubview(stream.view)

    stream.fullscreen = true
    stream.prepareToPlay()
    stream.play()

    stream.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
    stream.allowsAirPlay = true

    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
    try session.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("ERROR")
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not what you asked, but it is not usual to start playing _before_ you've configured your audio session.

Comment: I made the change - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there's a bug in the simulator: it does not simulate background modes correctly. You have not correctly configured your app for background production of sound, but the simulator fails to simulate this fact. Running on the device reveals the problem.

Comment: Any general ideas as to how to configure it to run for background production of sound?

Comment: Well, I noticed that, so I'm sorry I failed to mention it. But in my defense, I was concentrating on the question you asked - why the simulator and device work differently - rather than on the secondary question of _how_ to make your app play sound in the background, which I have thoroughly explained already elsewhere.